# How to get variable data by id

Tags: javascript, slider

Recently i have used  code in project that is still working it it http://kreditka.testovi-site.pw. But when i tried to reuse javascript the default rules  js got broken and i got an error in console explaining that varibale cannot be found. Is it somehow related that sme o the code is not resusable and each line should be rewritten one by one for defferent projects?

```
(function () {

    console.log("()");
    "use strict";
    var polosa = document.querySelector("#polosa");
    alert(polosa);
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#slide1");
    var o;
    for (o = 0; o < x.length; o++) {
        x[o].style.left = o*300+"px";
    }

    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#slide");
    var a;
    for (a = 0; a < x.length; a++) {
        x[a].style.left = a*300+"px";
    }

    var doc = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-click');
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
        doc[i].addEventListener("click", highlightThis, true);
    }

    var doc1 = document.querySelectorAll('.btn1-click');
    for (var j = 0; j < doc.length; j++) {
        doc1[j].addEventListener("click", highlightThis1, true);
    }

    var polosa = document.querySelector('#polosa');
    polosa.style.left = '0px';
    var left = 0;
    var sliderItem = document.querySelector('#slide');

    function highlightThis(event) {
        console.log("highlightThis");
        var currentActiveButton = document.querySelector(".btn-click.btn-slide-active");
        currentActiveButton.classList.toggle("btn-slide-active");
        event.target.classList.toggle("btn-slide-active");
        console.log(event.target.dataset.value);
        shiftSlide({
            prev: currentActiveButton.dataset.value,
            next: event.target.dataset.value
        });
    }
    function highlightThis1(event) {
        console.log("highlightThis1");
        var currentActiveButton1 = document.querySelector(".btn1-click.btn-slide-active");
        currentActiveButton1.classList.toggle("btn-slide-active");
        event.target.classList.toggle("btn-slide-active");
        console.log(event.target.dataset.value);
        shiftSlide1({
            prev: currentActiveButton1.dataset.value,
            next: event.target.dataset.value
        });
    }

    function shiftSlide(obj) {
        var polosa = document.querySelector('#polosa');
        console.log("shiftSlide");
        var currentSliderPosition = parseInt(polosa.style.left);
        if (obj.prev === obj.next) {
            return
        } else {
            var left = (obj.prev - obj.next) * 300;
            polosa.style.left = currentSliderPosition + left + "px";
        }

    }
    function shiftSlide1(obj) {
        var polosa = document.querySelector('#polosa1');
        console.log("shiftSlide");
        var currentSliderPosition = parseInt(polosa1.style.left);
        if (obj.prev === obj.next) {
            return
        } else {
            var left = (obj.prev - obj.next) * 300;
            polosa1.style.left = currentSliderPosition + left + "px";
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: What variable does the console say isn't defined?  Also, while using other peoples' examples is fine, you shouldn't blindly copy them and hope it works without understanding them.

Comment: polosa = document.querySelector('#polosa') were undefined and i tried to wrap in setTimout(function{},3000). I do understand each word in fucntion as it was installed and modified by me at least first part of it. Thanks or paying attention to this issue Snapjs.

Comment: Is there an element with  and id of `polosa` in your HTML?

Comment: There's something very fundamental that you should be made aware of: **An `#id` may only be assigned to an element on a webpage no more than once. `#id` must always be unique, there is no compromise.** Your page has 7 different elements with `id="recent"`. When you run JavaScript and it tries to look for an `#id` it will stop at the first one that matches and will go no further than that. So if you have 6 more identically `#id`'d elements, they will not be seen by the browser during transversal of DOM using JavaScript.